# Android development for sms related error

Tags: android, sms

When I am sending SMS using android code then it return RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE on same device(Samsung s7562)

```
String phoneNumber = "889999999";
String message = "MBL A2Z" ;
SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();
PendingIntent piSent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Mobile_recharge.this, 0, new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);
PendingIntent piDelivered=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Mobile_recharge.this, 0, new 
Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"), 0);
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, piSent, piDelivered);
```

Running above code on samsung s7562 it gives me `RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE`  error.

Comment: Please post the error logs.

Comment: i found RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE error on real device samsung s7562

Answer (score 0):

[link about error](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html#RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE)

check if you did these all :

```
import android.telephony.SmsManager;

SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
```

set this permission to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```